# Множество значений в 1 ajax запросе

Tags: javascript, html, c++, ajax, arduino

Всех приветствую. Недавно начал осваивать верстку и возникла проблема.

Разрабатываю интерфейс для IOT устройства, для обновления данных на экране использую ajax, но для того, чтобы обновить 3-4 значения нужно... использовать целых 4 запроса?

Можно ли как-то запросить множество параметров 1 запросом?

Сейчас использую это:

frontend:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'/>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <h1 style="text-align: center;"> v0.1 beta </h1>
</head>

<body>
    <script>

        window.onload = function () {
            getData();
        };

        setInterval(function () {
            getData();
        }, 2000); 
        
        function getData() {
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("current_temp").innerHTML =
                        this.responseText;
                }
            };
            xhttp.open("GET", "read_sensor", true);
            xhttp.send();
        }
    </script>

    <div id="real_values">
        Temp: <span id="current_temp">0.0</span>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

backend:

```
    void handle_view_sensor_value()
    {
    
      sensors.requestTemperatures();
    
      float temperatureC = sensors.getTempCByIndex(0);
    
      String adcValue = String(temperatureC);
    
      server.send(200, "text/plane", adcValue);
    
    }

  server.on("/view/read_sensor", handle_view_sensor_value); <- 1 запрос = 1 метод-обработчик, возвращающий.. всего лишь 1 значение.
```

то есть, мне нужно для каждого запроса создавать отдельные обработчики.

Можно ли 1 запросом взять несколько значений?

Может, для этого нужно вообще не ajax использовать?

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Возвращается не одно значение, а один ответ. В ответ можно засунуть любой формат данных, например JSON с кучей значений.

Comment: хм, а как можно спарсить json в ajax'е?

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте код js поместил перед </body>, дабы загрузился весь DOM.

Comment: @OliverPatterson, хорошо, учту

Comment: `хм, а как можно спарсить json в ajax'е?`: У вас есть `this.responseText` - это то, что вернул запрос, есть `JSON.parse` - `let res = JSON.parse(this.responseText)`.

Comment: @OliverPatterson, да-да, уже это понял. Вообще, это можно считать ответом, заверните свой коммент в ответ. Спасибо :)

Comment: `Я бы на вашем месте код js поместил перед </body>, дабы загрузился весь DOM. `, тогда можно убрать `window.onload`, а вызвать сразу функцию `getData()`, так же вместо `setInterval` лучше использовать `setTimeout`, что-бы не получилось, что "действия" накладываются.

Comment: @HWorld Раз уж тут советы начали давать, то почитайте о fetch. Измените тип на `application/json` и используйте [Body/json](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Body/json) без всякого `JSON.parse()`

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg, как раз таким вариантом и дополнил. Допроверялся, что заблокировали :D

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg, я, честно говоря, изначально затачивал под json, но не знал всех приколов JS'а с ним)

Comment: Не ожидал, что мой вопрос соберет столько людей) Спасибо всем!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно вернуть JSON строку и при принятия запроса преобразовать с помощью `JSON.parse( this.responseText)` в array/object.

Так же я бы переместил JS код перед закрывающим тегом `body`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'/>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <h1 style="text-align: center;"> v0.1 beta </h1>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="real_values">
        Temp: <span id="current_temp">0.0</span>
    </div>

    <script>
        getData();
        
        function getData() {
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    let data = JSON.parse(this.responseText); // получим array/object
                    // ...

                    // Запускаем вызов данной функции через 2 сек.
                    setTimeout(getData, 2000);
                }
            };
            xhttp.open("GET", "read_sensor", true);
            xhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

or

```js
function getData()
{
    fetch('read_sensor')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data =>
        {
            // в переменной data - array/object
            console.log('data: ', data)

            setTimeout(getData, 2000);
        })
    .catch(e =>
        {
            console.log('Error: ', e);
            setTimeout(getData, 2000);
        });
}
```

Comment: Не уверен, скорее всего можно убрать везде таймер и сделать `.then` с вызовом таймера после `.catch`.